# Web Tier Authentication in ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, .net, authentication

Can anyone explain me the steps, how to view map service from LDAP ,Web Tier Authenticated ArcGIS Server 10.2.1 in .net Application.

I have installed web adapter in Web server with windows authentication enabled.

When I open my application in my login I can see the map but with other system I can't see the map.

I am using Forms authentication in .net application.

Did I miss any configuring?

Comment: With Web Tier Auth, you still need to manage the users in ArcGIS Server. What login are you using in the other system?

Comment: I am using LDAP as forms authentication in Asp.net .Recently i went though documentation provided by esri on authentication.For LDAP authentication i need to deploy arcgis web adaptor on java application server ( i am using tomcat 6.0 here).I have installed and configured web adaptor. Next steps confuses me, i have no idea on configuration java application server for LDAP relam and   configure the authentication method for the Web Adaptor...any help on this